# Dynamic addition of item in List of tuples in Scala

Tags: list, scala, tuples

How can i add an item using loop in ListBuffer of tuples using Scala?
I have declared the List as:

```
val listV = new ListBuffer[(String,Int)]();
```

On adding item like this:

```
listV += ("a",1)
```

gives an error of : type mismatch as following

```
[error]  found   : String("a")

[error]  required: (String, Int)

[error]         listV += ("a",1)

[error]                   ^

[error] one error found
```

Any suggestions to resolve this ? Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Consider marking an answer as correct, so that this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 8):

`+=` is a method on `ListBuffer`, so the scala compiler thinks you're trying to pass two parameters to the `+=` method. You need an extra set of parenthesis to emphasize that the tuple is a single element and not an invalid parameter list.

```
listV += (("a", 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

More parentheses. `("a",1)` is interpreted as adding a `String` and an `Int` to `listV`.

```
scala> val listV = new ListBuffer[(String, Int)]
listV: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, Int)] = ListBuffer()

scala> listV += (("a", 1))
res0: listV.type = ListBuffer((a,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax which compiler can mix up with the function call:

```
listV += "a" -> 1
```

If you are more used to always having braces around Tuples this will also be interpreted correctly

```
listV += ("a" -> 1)
```